# Chaos game android

Tags: java, android

I am currently developing a "chaos game" for android. For those that don't know what it is: you pick some random numbers, and according to a given set of rules a dot is drawn somewhere on a canvas; after many iterations you get a shape, always the same.
In this case, it is a fern.

here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    DrawView drawView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        setContentView(drawView);
    }
}
```

DrawView.java

```
public class DrawView extends View{

    int viewWidth;
    int viewHeight;

    int iterations = 10000; // how many dots

    int myColor;

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Random rand = new Random();


    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        myColor = context.getResources().getColor(com.*****.******.*****.R.color.ferncolor); //Green

        paint.setColor(myColor);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld){
        super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);

        viewWidth = xNew;
        viewHeight = yNew;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Double x = rand.nextDouble();
        Double y = rand.nextDouble();
        Double random;

        for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
            random = rand.nextDouble();
            if(random < 0.01){
                x = 0.0;
                y *= 0.16;
            }               
            else if(random < 0.86){
                x = (0.85 * x) + (0.04 * y);
                y = (-0.04 * x) + (0.85 * y) + 1.6;
            }               
            else if(random < 0.93){
                x = (0.2 * x) - (0.26 * y);
                y = (0.23 * x) + (0.22 * y) + 1.6;
            }               
            else{
                x = (-0.15 * x) + (0.28 * y);
                y = (0.26 * x) + (0.24 * y) + 0.44;
            }

            Double posx = viewWidth/2.0 + x*viewWidth/7.5;
            Double posy = y*viewHeight/10.2;

            canvas.drawCircle(posx.floatValue(), posy.floatValue(), (float) 0.5, paint); //drawing dot at (posx,posy), size 0.5, with custom paint

        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that you have to wait for all the point to be drawn before you can see the view. That often leads to several awkward seconds blankness. What I would like is a "refresh" after every iteration (or every x iterations, depending on how much iterations I have).

I think that could be achieved *via* threading but I have no idea on how to achieve that.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can force a view to redraw by calling its `invalidate()` method. So you can try putting that at the end of your `for` loop.

More information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29).

Also, invalidating too often could cause a performace slowdown, so if you want to draw 10000 dots, you could probably call invalidate only on every 500th iteration or something...

Comment: Thanks, but calling invalidate redraws my view, and I want to keep the dots I already have. My goal is to get as many dots as possible without waiting by drawing them progressively and updating rather than deleting what already has been drawn.

Comment: Well, the view should remember what its children are (in this case the dots) and redraw them anytime the view itself is drawn... So I actually find it a bit weird that calling `invalidate()` removes previously drawn views. But I haven't done an Android app in a while and I currently don't even have the SDK installed, so unfortunately I can't help you more.